# Recyclerview holder setting an image text instead of drawable

Tags: android

I need your help to display the array texts as image, displaying them as text is working, but is image is not working. below are some explanation.

I have an array of texts that I want to display them in recycler view as an image.

```
String[] images =
        {
                "for_honor.png",
                "R.drawable.ghost_recon.png",
                "R.drawable.horizon_zerod.png",
                "R.drawable.mass_effect.png"
        };
```

setting them in this way seems wrong as i am not getting image

```
            ((MyViewHolder) holder).getmDataImgView().getResources().getIdentifier(name,"drawable","com.example.pkg.pg.Adapters");
```

however this code is working it show me them as text not image

```
       //     ((MyViewHolder) holder).getmDataTextView().setText(name);
```

this code im my main activity

```
      MainGridRecView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.maingridrc);
      MainGridRecViewLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(context);
      MainGridRecView.setLayoutManager(MainGridRecViewLayoutManager);

    MainGridRecViewAdapter = new MainGridRvAdapter( dataHorizontal,dataVertical,MainActivity.this);

      MainGridRecView.setAdapter(MainGridRecViewAdapter);
```

this maingridrvadapter

```
public class MainGridRvAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> {
    private final Context mContext;
    private ArrayList<ListMainItem> dataHorizontal;
    private ArrayList<ListMainItem> dataVertical;
    private static final int TYPE_HEADER = 0;
    private static final int TYPE_ITEM = 1;

    public MainGridRvAdapter(ArrayList<ListMainItem> dataHorizontal, ArrayList<ListMainItem> dataVertical, Context context) {
        setDataHorizontal(dataHorizontal);
        setDataVertical(dataVertical);
        mContext = context;
    }

    @Override
    public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        if (viewType == TYPE_ITEM) {
            //inflate your layout and pass it to view holder
            View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.row, parent, false);
            return new MyViewHolder(v);
        } else if (viewType == TYPE_HEADER) {
            //inflate your layout and pass it to view holder
            View v =  LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.row_header, parent, false);
            return new MyViewHolderHeader(v);
        }
        throw new RuntimeException("there is no type that matches the type " + viewType + " + make sure your using types correctly");

    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        if (holder instanceof MyViewHolder) {
            String name = getDataVertical().get(position-1).getImages();
            Log.d("###", "Setting name: " + name);

            ((MyViewHolder) holder).getmDataImgView().getResources().getIdentifier(name,"drawable","com.example.pkg.pg.Adapters");
           // int resourceId = Activity.getResources().getIdentifier("testimage", "drawable", "your.package.name");

        } else if (holder instanceof MyViewHolderHeader) {
            //cast holder to VHHeader and set data for header.
            Log.d("####", "HEADER");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return dataVertical.size() + 1;
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        if (isPositionHeader(position)) {
            return TYPE_HEADER;
        }

        return TYPE_ITEM;
    }

    private boolean isPositionHeader(int position) {
        return position == 0;
    }

    public void setDataHorizontal(ArrayList<ListMainItem> dataHorizontal) {
        this.dataHorizontal = dataHorizontal;
    }

    public ArrayList<ListMainItem> getDataHorizontal() {
        return dataHorizontal;
    }

    public void setDataVertical(ArrayList<ListMainItem> dataVertical) {
        this.dataVertical = dataVertical;
    }

    public ArrayList<ListMainItem> getDataVertical() {
        return dataVertical;
    }

    private class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
   //     private final TextView mDataTextView;
        private final ImageView mDataImgView;

        public MyViewHolder(View v) {
            super(v);
        //    mDataTextView = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.data_vertical);
            mDataImgView = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.img_vertical);

        }
/*
        public TextView getmDataTextView() {
            return mDataTextView;
        }*/
        public ImageView getmDataImgView() {
            return mDataImgView;
        }
    }

    private class MyViewHolderHeader extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        private final RecyclerView mHorizontalRecyclerView;

        public MyViewHolderHeader(View v) {
            super(v);
            mHorizontalRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) v.findViewById(R.id.recycler_view_horizontal);
            RecyclerViewAdapterHorizontal mAdapter = new RecyclerViewAdapterHorizontal(getDataHorizontal());
            LinearLayoutManager layoutManager
                    = new LinearLayoutManager(mContext, LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false);

            mHorizontalRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
            mHorizontalRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
        }
    }
}
```

layout

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/data_vertical"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="text"
    />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/img_vertical"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

```
class RecyclerViewAdapterHorizontal extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> {
    private final ArrayList<ListMainItem> mData;
    private final Context mContext;

    public RecyclerViewAdapterHorizontal(ArrayList<ListMainItem> dataHorizontal,Context context) {
        mData = dataHorizontal;
        mContext=context;
    }

    @Override
    public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.row, parent, false);
        return new RecyclerViewAdapterHorizontal.MyViewHolderHeader(v);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        String name = mData.get(position).getImages();
        Log.d("###", "Setting name: " + name);
     //   ((RecyclerViewAdapterHorizontal.MyViewHolderHeader) holder).getmDataTextView().setText(name);
          ((RecyclerViewAdapterHorizontal.MyViewHolderHeader) holder).getmDataImgView().setImageResource(mContext.getResources().getIdentifier(name, "drawable", "com.example.mohamadmouazen.lebgame.Adapters"));



    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mData.size();
    }

    private class MyViewHolderHeader extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
       // private final TextView mDataTextView;
          private final ImageView mDataImgView;

        public MyViewHolderHeader(View v) {
            super(v);
            //    mDataTextView = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.data_vertical);
            mDataImgView = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.img_vertical);
        }

        public ImageView getmDataImgView() {
            return mDataImgView;
        }
/*        public TextView getmDataTextView() {
            return mDataTextView;
        }*/
    }
```

edit

```
class RecyclerViewAdapterHorizontal extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> {
    private final ArrayList<ListMainItem> mData;
    private final Context mContext;

    public RecyclerViewAdapterHorizontal(ArrayList<ListMainItem> dataHorizontal,Context context) {
        mData = dataHorizontal;
        mContext=context;
    }

    @Override
    public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.row, parent, false);
        return new RecyclerViewAdapterHorizontal.MyViewHolderHeader(v);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        String name = mData.get(position).getImages();
        Log.d("###", "Setting name: " + name);
     //   ((RecyclerViewAdapterHorizontal.MyViewHolderHeader) holder).getmDataTextView().setText(name);
          ((RecyclerViewAdapterHorizontal.MyViewHolderHeader) holder).getmDataImgView().setImageResource(mContext.getResources().getIdentifier(name, "drawable", "com.example.pkg.pg.Adapters"));

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mData.size();
    }

    private class MyViewHolderHeader extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
       // private final TextView mDataTextView;
          private final ImageView mDataImgView;

        public MyViewHolderHeader(View v) {
            super(v);
            //    mDataTextView = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.data_vertical);
            mDataImgView = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.img_vertical);
        }

        public ImageView getmDataImgView() {
            return mDataImgView;
        }
/*        public TextView getmDataTextView() {
            return mDataTextView;
        }*/
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Change your `images` array to `int`s:

```
int[] images = {
    R.drawable.for_honor,
    R.drawable.ghost_recon,
    R.drawable.horizon_zerod,
    R.drawable.mass_effect
};
```

and set the image something like so:

```
int resourceId = images[position]; // <-- apply your actual logic here
...getmDataImgView().setImageResource(resourceId);
```

Comment: when i removed the quotes "" .. i get error on `.png`

Comment: Delete .png suffix from all your elements. R.drawable.something is an indication to a specific int created by the system which points to the resource you want.

Comment: @antonis_st thanks; i missed that. Fixed it in the example code now.

Answer (score 0):

A method `int getIdentifier (String name, String defType, String defPackage)` returns resource identifier for the given resource name. In other words it returns the `R.drawable.your_name` .

When you set the text it works because `TextView` is expecting the String type.

Plus you actually do not set anything to your `ImageView`. Your mistake is here:

```
((MyViewHolder) holder).getmDataImgView().getResources().getIdentifier(name,"drawable","com.example.pkg.pg.Adapters");
```

You just getting the identifier from the resource. Instead to set the image you should do:

```
((MyViewHolder) holder).getmDataImgView().setImageResource(mContext.getResources().getIdentifier(name,"drawable","com.example.pkg.pg.Adapters"));
```

By the way it is not reccomended to hardcode your resources names in the string. Do it in the proper way by setting resource identifier directly.

Comment: this way is getting error `((MyViewHolder) holder).getmDataImgView().setImageResource(getResources()` on get reresources

Comment: hi i edit my question , i added  another class that am setting the image but still the image not showing , thats weird. becauase in the log i am gettingthe name of the image

Comment: @Moudiz what do you get on Setting name: ?